# Firestore security rules without the authentication through the javascript

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Iam facing a issue of Insecure rules in firestore.

We are having a website for that there is no login required through that we are writing some data into the database.

For which we are allowing every user to write into our db for which we are getting the insecure rules issue from firestore guys. We are banging our heads but did not find a solution for it.

```
    allow read: if true;
    allow create: if request.resource.data.invites is string && request.resource.data.invites >= 1 && request.resource.data.invites < 13;

    allow update : if request.auth.uid != null;
```

Please help me out,

Thnx
Ramya

Comment: Allowing anyone to write data to your database is insecure, which is the issue. What's your question?

Comment: Hey Jay I Know that it is not secure but how can i make it secure .I think there is possibility in making it secure by writing some condition based on the feilds of that particular document .when I tried the above code it shows "writing insufficent permission" so how can I add "write" rule for unaunthenticated users in database

Comment: FireStore & Firebase are secured through Rules. If you don't secure it, anyone could write unlimited data to your firebase at any time, and that could impact you financially - if they wanted to be malicious, any kinda of data could be written, corrupting your structures.